# Bug with Asp.Net 3.5? - Is it fixed in 4.0 or still need reporting?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a Request.PathInfo such as the url

`http://localhost/default.aspx/test`

and a Button with no PostBackUrl set (aka it is "") and I click it,

it changes the url to `http://localhost/default.aspx/default.aspx`

Is this a bug/feature and if it is a bug, was it fixed in 4.0?

Edit: was a Button control not LinkButton

Run this page, put in /test after the page name and click the button.  The /test is removed and exchanged with the name of the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is not a bug so much as you are using things in an unsupported or unexpected manner.  Why are you doing this anyways?

Comment: Simple Edit button to open an editable text box.

Comment: No, I mean why are you using the path the way that you are.  Standard asp.net demands that pages end in .aspx, and query strings use the ? syntax.  If you want to do things a different way, you have to use some kind of url rewriting that will rewrite to an accepted format.

Comment: You should check out Request.PathInfo then.  Because no it doesn't.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx

Comment: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770152